# Show/hide part of external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show/hide the answers for below external .js file using a 'toggle' button ? If I had access to the code I could wrap the answers in a div but since this is an external .js file is this possible ?

Heres the fiddle & code :

http://jsfiddle.net/Wx5mM/

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".pds-pd-link").hide();
        $(".a2a_dd.pds-share").hide();
        $(".pds-box").width(220);
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>
    <noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/5968383/">This is a test question ?</a></noscript>
```

Comment: Mmm... I don't really get. Btw if your poll is coming from polldaddy maybe you're including a JS that creates an iframe that resided on a different server from your original page. In this case you can't operate on the iframe, because is coming from a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external JavaScript just adds elements to the DOM so its possible to manipulate them using jQuery, something like this would work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pds-question').append('<input type="button" class="showanswer" value="show answer"/>');
    $('.pds-answer').hide();
    $('.showanswer').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next().show();
    });
});​
```

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wx5mM/9/)**

Use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add `button`, then hide the answers. The [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function then shows the answers

Comment: Should this also work in IE8 ? I receive an errror : "Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 28 Jun 2012 10:37:57 UTC


Message: '_container' is null or not an object
Line: 63
Char: 6669
Code: 0
URI: http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343643.js

"

Comment: I think jsfiddle is down, can you access it ?